# Google Apps API (Calendar v3) returns 404 error

Tags: api, calendar

I had been working with the Google API (Calendar v3) for a while without problems until I started to receive error messages a week ago. I can still authorize but any request I make returns a 404 error. I also tried to use another Google Apps account and had the same issue.

```
// Load the API and make an API call.
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() { 
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({ 
            'calendarId': 'primary' 
        }); 
        request.execute(function(resp) { 
            console.log (resp);
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

The console log is:
code: 404
data: Array[1]
error: Object
message: "Not Found"
**proto**: Object